# Select Query on xml data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have;

```
declare @result xml
set @result='<root><data><color20>red</color20></data></root>'

select tab.col('@color20','varchar(500)'
    from @result.nodes(/data)tab(col)
```

I want to bring 20 from variable called @period

```
select tab.col('@color+'+@period+'','varchar(500)'
    from @result.nodes(/data)tab(col)
```

when i run above query i am getting below error
The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query

```
declare @result xml
set @result='<root><data><color20>red</color20><color21>blue</color21></data></root>'
declare @period varchar(10)
set @period='20'

select tab.col.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)') as Name,
   tab.col.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value 
from @result.nodes('/root/data/*')tab(col)
where tab.col.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)')='color'+ @period
```